# Data not getting loaded into Partitioned Table in Hive

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive, partition

I am trying to create partition for my Table inorder to update a value.

This is my sample data

```
1,Anne,Admin,50000,A
2,Gokul,Admin,50000,B
3,Janet,Sales,60000,A
```

I want to update `Janet's` Department to **B**.

So for doing that I created a table with Department as partition.

> create external table trail (EmployeeID Int,FirstName
>   String,Designation  String,Salary Int) PARTITIONED BY (Department
>   String) row format delimited fields terminated by "," location
>   '/user/sreeveni/HIVE';

But while doing the above command.
No data are inserted into trail table.

```
hive>select * from trail;                               
OK
Time taken: 0.193 seconds

hive>desc trail;                                        
OK
employeeid              int                     None                
firstname               string                  None                
designation             string                  None                
salary                  int                     None                
department              string                  None                

# Partition Information      
# col_name              data_type               comment             

department              string                  None
```

Am I doing anything wrong?

**UPDATE**

As suggested I tried to insert data into my table

> load data inpath '/user/aibladmin/HIVE' overwrite into table trail
>   Partition(Department);

But it is showing

> FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10096]: Dynamic partition strict mode
>   requires at least one static partition column. To turn this off set 
>   hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict

After setting `set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict` also didnt work fine.

Anything else to do.

Answer (score 24):

Try both below properties

```
SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition = true;
SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode = nonstrict;
```

And while writing insert statement for a partitioned table make sure that you specify the partition columns at the last in select clause.

Comment: im trying to `insert into select` to a partition table. The data is only 13k records. After using the above setting the query runs. but i get memory run our issue. Wonder, for a fairly small data it should not run out of memory.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot directly insert data(Hdfs File) into a Partitioned hive table.
First you need to create a normal table, then you will insert that table data into partitioned table.

`set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=strict` means when ever you are populating hive table it must have at least one static partition column.

`set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict` In this mode you don't need any static partition column.

Comment: How do you create a static partition column?

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

Start by creating the table:

```
create external table test23 (EmployeeID Int,FirstName String,Designation String,Salary Int) PARTITIONED BY (Department String) row format delimited fields terminated by "," location '/user/rocky/HIVE';
```

Create a directory in hdfs with partition name :

```
$ hadoop fs -mkdir /user/rocky/HIVE/department=50000
```

Create a local file `abc.txt` by filtering records having department equal to 50000:

```
$ cat abc.txt 
1,Anne,Admin,50000,A
2,Gokul,Admin,50000,B
```

Put it into HDFS:

```
$ hadoop fs -put /home/yarn/abc.txt /user/rocky/HIVE/department=50000
```

Now alter the table:

```
ALTER TABLE test23 ADD PARTITION(department=50000);
```

And check the result:

```
select * from test23 ;
```

Answer (score 1):

just set those 2 properties BEFORE you `getOrCreate()` the spark session:

```
SparkSession
    .builder
    .config(new SparkConf())
    .appName(appName)
    .enableHiveSupport()
    .config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition","true")
    .config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode", "nonstrict")
    .getOrCreate()
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem and yes these two properties are needed. However, I used JDBC driver with Scala to set these properties before executing Hive statements. The problem, however, was that I was executing a bunch of properties (SET statements) in one execution statement like this

```
     conn = DriverManager.getConnection(conf.get[String]("hive.jdbc.url"))
     conn.createStatement().execute(
"SET spark.executor.memory = 2G;
SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode = nonstrict; 
SET hive.other.statements =blabla  ;")
```

For some reason, the driver was not able to interpret all these as separate statements, so I needed to execute each one of them separately.

```
  conn = DriverManager.getConnection(conf.get[String]("hive.jdbc.url"))
    conn.createStatement().execute("SET spark.executor.memory = 2G;")
    conn.createStatement().execute("SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;") 
   conn.createStatement().execute("SET hive.other.statements =blabla  ;")
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try running 
MSCK REPAIR TABLE table_name;

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-RecoverPartitions(MSCKREPAIRTABLE)